# dplyr - mutate formula based on similarities in column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find a better way to run a `mutate()` on a combination of columns based on parts of the column names.

For example, a way to simplify the `mutate` function in the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(LIMITED_A = c(100,200),
                UNLIMITED_A = c(25000,50000),
                LIMITED_B = c(300,300),
                UNLIMITED_B = c(500,500),
                LIMITED_C = c(2,10),
                UNLIMITED_C = c(5,20))

df %>%
  mutate(FINAL_LIMITED = (LIMITED_A - LIMITED_B) / LIMITED_C,
         FINAL_UNLIMITED = (UNLIMITED_A - UNLIMITED_B) / UNLIMITED_C)
```

A formula with the form: `(._A - ._B) / ._C` and the result is given the name `FINAL_.`

Is there a way to simplify this to a single line of code in the `mutate` function?

Comment: @bouncyball changed the variable to `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(glue)

dynamic_mutate = function(DF,  
                          col_names = gsub("(.*)_\\w+$", "\\1", names(DF)), 
                          expression = "({x}_A - {x}_B)/{x}_C",
                          prefix = "FINAL"){

  name_list = col_names %>% 
    unique() %>%
    as.list()

  expr_list = name_list %>%
    lapply(function(x) parse_quosure(glue(expression))) %>% 
    setNames(paste(prefix, name_list, sep = "_")) 

  DF %>% mutate(!!!expr_list)

}
```

**Result:**

```
> df %>%
+   dynamic_mutate()
  LIMITED_A UNLIMITED_A LIMITED_B UNLIMITED_B LIMITED_C UNLIMITED_C FINAL_LIMITED
1       100       25000       300         500         2           5          -100
2       200       50000       300         500        10          20           -10
  FINAL_UNLIMITED
1            4900
2            2475

> df %>%
+   dynamic_mutate(c("LIMITED", "UNLIMITED"), prefix = "NEW")
  LIMITED_A UNLIMITED_A LIMITED_B UNLIMITED_B LIMITED_C UNLIMITED_C NEW_LIMITED
1       100       25000       300         500         2           5        -100
2       200       50000       300         500        10          20         -10
  NEW_UNLIMITED
1          4900
2          2475

> df %>%
+   dynamic_mutate(c("UNLIMITED"), prefix = "NEW")
  LIMITED_A UNLIMITED_A LIMITED_B UNLIMITED_B LIMITED_C UNLIMITED_C NEW_UNLIMITED
1       100       25000       300         500         2           5          4900
2       200       50000       300         500        10          20          2475

> df %>% 
+   dynamic_mutate(c("A", "B", "C"), "LIMITED_{x} + UNLIMITED_{x}")
  LIMITED_A UNLIMITED_A LIMITED_B UNLIMITED_B LIMITED_C UNLIMITED_C FINAL_A FINAL_B FINAL_C
1       100       25000       300         500         2           5   25100     800       7
2       200       50000       300         500        10          20   50200     800      30
```

**Notes:**

This approach uses `lapply` and `glue` to construct expressions from prefixes extracted using `gsub` (or you can supply your own prefixes/suffixes). `parse_quosure` from `rlang` is then used to parse the expression into a `quosure`. As a result, `expr_list` is a named list of `quosure`'s which I can then use `!!!` to unquote and splice the arguments into separate expressions in `mutate`.

You can change the formula by adjusting the `expression` argument as shown in the last example.

The advantage of this method is that it is quite fast because I am mainly manipulating column names and creating strings (expressions). The disadvantage is that it uses multiple packages.

Comment: using your solution above following the same steps i got this error          error: The quosure environment should be explicitly supplied as `env`

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to convert the data frame to long format and conduct the calculation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(Type, Value, -ID) %>%
  separate(Type, into = c("Type", "Group")) %>%
  spread(Group, Value) %>%
  mutate(Final = (A - B)/C)
df2
  ID      Type     A   B  C Final
1  1   LIMITED   100 300  2  -100
2  1 UNLIMITED 25000 500  5  4900
3  2   LIMITED   200 300 10   -10
4  2 UNLIMITED 50000 500 20  2475
```

And you can always convert the data frame back to the wide format.

```
df3 <- df2 %>%
  gather(Group, Value, A:Final) %>%
  unite(Col, Type, Group) %>%
  spread(Col, Value) %>%
  select(colnames(df), 
         FINAL_LIMITED = LIMITED_Final, 
         FINAL_UNLIMITED = UNLIMITED_Final)
  LIMITED_A UNLIMITED_A LIMITED_B UNLIMITED_B LIMITED_C UNLIMITED_C FINAL_LIMITED FINAL_UNLIMITED
1       100       25000       300         500         2           5          -100            4900
2       200       50000       300         500        10          20           -10            2475
```

Comment: using theabove solution i got this error Column `ID` must be length 0 (the number of rows) or one, not 2